# Indexed Event with string not getting logged

Tags: solidity, events, string

I am facing a strange issue in my solidity smart contract using events. I created the event in 2 ways as below:-

```
1. event Event1(string assetName, address toAdd);
2. event Event1(string indexed assetName, address indexed toAdd);
```

Now if I run my smart contract and I have specified approach 1, then the event gets printed in the console logs whereas if I use approach 2, then the event is not printed in the console logs.

Can someone clarify on this?

**Note**: Not pasting the whole contract code

Comment: Show us the javascript code.

Comment: var event = contract1.Event1({},'',function(err,result){
 console.log('new  event::' + JSON.stringify(result));
});

Comment: Did you redeploy the contract ? and updated the contract1 abi ? after the change ?

Comment: I recreated the contract at a different address, with indexed event it didn't work and without index, it worked.

Answer (score 24):

The combination of `string` and `indexed` does not work. To understand why, see how event arguments are stored in the blockchain.

All transactions that are executed generate a transaction receipt, which contains a property called `logs`. You can look up the receipt using `eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x...")`.

In the transaction receipt, all event arguments that are not `indexed` are included in the `data` property. This property can hold values of arbitrary length. However, event arguments that are `indexed` are not stored in the `data` property, but end up in `topics`. This allows filters to work.

For fixed size arguments types this is ok. The size of the entries in `topics` is long enough to hold all fixed types supported by Solidity. However, `string` can have an arbitrary length. To still be able to store those values in a topic, Solidity creates a hash of the value, which ends up in the topic.

The upside is that filters can still work, since you can just create the hash of the value you're filtering for. The downside is that web3 is unable to decode the value, since that would require performing the hash function in reverse direction.

To solve this problem, you have two options. You can remove `indexed` from the argument, so it is stored in the `data` field and no longer hashed to become part of a topic. Or, you change the type of the argument, e.g. into `bytes32` or another. Which is appropriate depends on your case.

Comment: You can always `keccak256(your_string_here)`  _(`web3.sha3("your_string_here")`)_

Answer (score 4):

You can workaround that by creating 2 parameters for the same attribute, one indexed and the other not indexed, like:

```
event Event1(string indexed indexedAssetName, address indexed toAdd, string assetName);
```

Then you pass the same value to both, like this:

```
emit Event1("assetName", address, "assetName");
```

When searching you use the indexed parameter, when outputting you use the other one.

Answer (score 1):

- As you are referring to assets in your code.
- As answered below about 256-bit limitation of indexed values

-> You can index maximum of 32 8-bit characters

-> Add unique symbol string to all of your assets, 32 characters each

-> Use this instead of asset name in smart contracts

-> Maintain external asset symbol -> asset name (asset data) registry outside blockchain