# How to filter and access the unindexed event parameters?

Tags: events, the-graph

I was doing a project, and I have an event

```js
event AddedDoctor(
        address indexed doctorAddress,
        string indexed name, 
        string indexed doctorRegistrationId,
        uint256 dateOfRegistration,
        string specialization,
        address hospitalAddress
    );
```

I am not able to access all the parameters of this event to index it is `The Graph`. I am facing two issues :

1. `string indexed name` parameter is indexed so it is accessible by `event.params.name` but it is in the `Bytes` format. On searching the net I found that indexed strings or arrays are stored as hashes and not plain strings. How do I get unstuck.
2. I am not able to read unindexed parameters `string specialization` and `address hospitalAddress` using `event.params.specialization` and `event.params.hospitalAddress`. How do I access these unindexed parameters?

Basically I want to index all these event parameters in `The Graph` for easy retrieval of data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found that `The Graph` can index the unindexed string parameter in the string format and we can directly work with that. The `indexed` string parameters are hashed into into 20 bytes object which is difficult to work with. I found this answer:

[Indexed Event with string not getting logged](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/indexed-event-with-string-not-getting-logged)

So, basically I removed `indexed` keyword from all the parameters of `string` or `array` type and it works.